# GMail not returning bounced email

Tags: java, email, gmail

We have a Java application that sends email through our corporate Google provided email accounts.  It works fine in most cases, but when we have a wrong email address we never receive a bounce email back no matter where we send it.

However, if I log in to the same email account and send to the same bad email address, I do get a bounce message back.

Why don't I get a bounce message when I send email programmatically?

Here is our code that sends email:

```
private void sendMessageImpl(String toAddresses, String replyToAddress, String subject, String body, int failedAttempts, long startTime) throws MessagingException {
    final Properties properties = getMailProperties();

    String fromAddress = properties.getProperty("mail.from");        
    Session session = getSession();
    Transport transport = null;
    boolean tryingToConnect = false;

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        toAddresses = toAddresses.replaceAll(";", ",");
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddresses));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);

        // Send the message
        transport = session.getTransport(message.getAllRecipients()[0]);
        tryingToConnect = true;
        transport.connect();
        tryingToConnect = false;
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        transport = null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Fail to send email to " + toAddresses+". Subject: "+subject+"\nContents: "+body, e);
        throw new MessagingException("Mail Failure");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Fail to send email to " + toAddresses+". Subject: "+subject+"\nContents: "+body, e);
    } finally {
        if(transport != null) {
            try {
                transport.close();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(Mail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to close transport after earlier error left it open. ", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the _actual_ value of `fromAddress`?

Comment: The from address is a group alias that goes to a number of people.  It is a our support email address, so support@<mycompany>.com .

Comment: From the Javadoc: _"An appropriate TransportEvent indicating the delivery status is delivered to any TransportListener registered on this Transport"_ -- can you register a `TransportListener` to intercept any status information?

Comment: @JimGarrison That is worth taking a look at.